# How can I add multi-column sorting to jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I can add single column sorting to jqgrid, no problem. How can I add multi-column sorting to jqgrid?

That is, sort by column 1, then sort by column 2, the final sort order is: column 2, column 1

Answer (score 12):

Current version of jqGrid not support multi-column sorting.

On http://www.trirand.com/blog/ you can "Which feature do you like to see in jqGrid?" vote the answer

- Export to PDF
- Freeze columns
- **Sort by multiple columns**
- Group by multiple columns

In general you can try to implement multi-sorting yourself by modifying `sortname` and `sortorder` parameters of jqGrid inside [onSortCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler with respect of [setGridParam](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). In case of two columns which having column indexes like `firstName` and `lastName` for example the sorting by the first column only imply having `sortname` as 'firstName' and `sortorder` as 'asc'. If you want to sort first by the `firstName` and by `lastName` as the secont criteria you can set `sortname` as 'firstName asc, lastName' and `sortorder` as 'asc'. Your server program should of cause be able to interpret this, but if you just construct `ORDER BY` something like `ORDER BY $sidx $sord` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#php_and_mysql_example_file) it will work.

Comment: Too bad at this time sort by multiple columns is 3rd :(

Answer (score 7):

A simple work around is to list all fields as a comma separated string ex.

```
sortname: 'customer_id, store_id, start_date'
```

On the server side just go ahead and parse the string and and craft your query.