# Sort 2nd column based on first column sort using tablesorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

when first column is clicked for sorting, it should sort first column and then 2nd column based on first column.
but when other columns are clicked they should sort as they should 
e.g.
Name  ID
Abc   1
ghi   3
cde   2
trg   5
def   4

when name is sorted it should show up like
Name  ID
Abc   1
cde   2
def   4
ghi   3
trg   5

when other columns are sorted they should sort accordingly without any link to other column
i tried sortForce, but it force always on column provided in it

Answer (score 0):

Related post here: [How can I add multi-column sorting to jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632526/how-can-i-add-multi-column-sorting-to-jqgrid)

Related post is in regards to multi column sorting using the jqGrid jQuery plugin.